# Fingerprint Verification with BearSSL on ESP8266 (Arduino IDE)

Tags: ssl, encryption, arduino-esp8266, fingerprinting

I'm using BearSSL from the Arduino provided Librarys, namely the class WiFiSecureClient. I took the reference implementation to get a secure TCP connection between a simple Python implemented server and the ESP8266 board as a client.

I exported the key and certificate with OpenSSL and used them to feed the Python socket SSL wrapper. 
Everything works fine, messages can be exchanged, however the certificate can not be verified by the WifiSecureClient. Here a partial code of the node:

```
void handle() {
  // Use WiFiClientSecure class to create TLS connection

  WiFiClientSecure client;
  client.allowSelfSignedCerts();

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  if (client.verify(fingerprint, host)) {
    Serial.println("certificate matches");
  } else {
    Serial.println("certificate doesn't match");
  }


  client.print("Some Message");
  Serial.println("request sent");

  String line;
  while (client.connected()) {
    line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  }

  Serial.println("reply was:");
  Serial.println("==========");
  Serial.println(line);
  Serial.println("==========");
  Serial.println("closing connection");
  client.stop();
}
```

As mentioned, I can send and receive messages (I don't know if they are encrypted or on fallback unencrypted) but the step

```
  if (client.verify(fingerprint, host)) {
    Serial.println("certificate matches");
  } else {
    Serial.println("certificate doesn't match");
  }
```

always fails.The fingerprint was exported with OpenSSL as a SHA1 key. I double checked this by connecting to the server with another PC, fetching the certificate and recalculating its fingerprint. THe Code works fine if I try to contact a public server like api.github.com (which was default in the example). As you can see I already allowed for self signed certificates by calling the appropriate API method of BearSSL.

Is there anything I've missed, e.g. do I have to have a whole keychain or something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that the "host" argument of verify() must match the certificate common name (in your case  *.github.com or api.github.com):

Test: `openssl s_client -connect api.github.com:443`

Output: `0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=*.github.com`